# How to remap my 2d array to target schema using RxJS?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

**UPDATE** I found a possible answer I added at the end of my question and wonder if there's a more elegant solution.

I have a two dimensional array that I want to remap for an Angular 9 app. I'm trying to use RxJS operators to accomplish this and I have had partial success.

My goal is to group all the *_id* data by *row* number and place under the root level property *dataset*, then add the property *iconDefault*  & *row*.

I can build this with some loops but I would like to learn more of RxJS.

**My source 2d array:**

```
[
  [
    {
      "_id": "5efbb97e80752985301c3447",
      "row": 1,
      "position": 0,
      "tab": 1
    },
    {
      "_id": "5efbb97e80752985301c3453",
      "row": 1,
      "position": 1,
      "tab": 1
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "_id": "5efbb97e80752985301c3411",
      "row": 2,
      "position": 0,
      "tab": 1
    },
    {
      "_id": "5efbb97e80752985301c3414",
      "row": 2,
      "position": 1,
      "tab": 1
    },
    {
      "_id": "5efbb97e80752985301c33f3",
      "row": 2,
      "position": 2,
      "tab": 1
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "_id": "5efbb97e80752985301c343b",
      "row": 3,
      "position": 0,
      "tab": 1
    }
  ]
]
```

**The result I want:**

```
{
    "tab": 1,
    "dataset": [{
        "row": 1,
        "iconDefault": "5e7824c67bd78eb199e95f3e",
        "ids": ["5efbb97e80752985301c3447",
            "5efbb97e80752985301c3453"
        ]
    }, {
        "row": 2,
        "iconDefault": "5e7824c67bd78eb199e95f3e",
        "ids": ["5efbb97e80752985301c3411",
            "5efbb97e80752985301c3414",
            "5efbb97e80752985301c33f3"
        ]
    }, {
        "row": 3,
        "iconDefault": "5e7824c67bd78eb199e95f3e",
        "ids": ["5efbb97e80752985301c343b"]
    }]
}
```

**The closest result I can come up with:**

```
{
  "dataset": [
    [
      "5efbb97e80752985301c3447",
      "5efbb97e80752985301c3453"
    ],
    [
      "5efbb97e80752985301c3411",
      "5efbb97e80752985301c3414",
      "5efbb97e80752985301c33f3"
    ],
    [
      "5efbb97e80752985301c343b"
    ]
  ],
  "tab": 1
}
```

I define the source 2d array and use this code to generate my result

```js
  // source defined from 2d array above
  let updatePackage = {};
  updatePackage.dataset = source.map((subarray) =>
     subarray.map((row) => row._id)
  );
  updatePackage.tab = 1; //manual set but would be better from data
  console.log(updatePackage);
  document.body.append(JSON.stringify(updatePackage));
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/chrisloughnane/81tycj46/)

**My OCD Solution:**

```js
let updatePackage = {} as any;
        updatePackage.tab = 1;
        let dataset = [] as any;
        dataset = this.rows.map((subarray) => subarray.map((row) => row._id));
        updatePackage.dataset = dataset.map((row, rowIndex = 0) => {
          rowIndex++;
          return {
            row: rowIndex,
            ids: row,
            iconDefault: '5e7824c67bd78eb199e95f3e',
          };
        });
```

[OCD Solution JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chrisloughnane/8jqcpdbu/)

Comment: what is the type of the items you receive each time ? each item is a two dimensional array ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach:

```js
src$.pipe(
  // If `src$` emits `[[a, b], [c, d]]`,
  // by applying `mergeAll`, we'd get `[a, b]`, `[c, d]`, separately
  mergeAll(),

  // Might want to filter out empty arrays
  filter(arr => arr.length !== 0),

  map(
    arr => arr.reduce(
      (acc, crt) => (acc.ids.push(crt._id), acc), 
      { iconDefault: "5e7824c67bd78eb199e95f3e", ids: [], row: arr[0].row }
    )
  ),

  scan(
    (acc, crt) => (acc.dataset.push(crt), acc),
    { tab: 1, dataset: [] },
  )
)
```

Depending on how you want to manage `tabs`, you might have to change the logic a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to test it in my code but I get `Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'any[]'`. The **rows** array is set by an emitter from another component and although I tried to adjust your approach to use the subscribe attached to the emitter that didn't work either.

Comment: *without a doubt I need to examine how my back end logic matches my front end. I'm working on an old project that I'm updating to Angular 9 as a learning exercise.